# Is it possible to create a easy dictonary only one line?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This question maybe is meaningless.
We always create a list by only one line,like

```
Onelist = [ _ for _ in range(5)]
```

to create a list `0-4`.

If I want to create a dictionary `Result`:

```
CountList = ["zero","one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine"]
Result = {
    "zero":0,
    "one":0,
    # each value is zero
xxxxx
}
```

Is there a pythonic way to do this?

Comment: "We always create a list by only one line,like" No we don't. You would usually just use `list(range(4))`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga hahaha.....,there is no one like this,just me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create dictionaries in the similar way you create lists using list comprehension:

```
CountList = ["zero","one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine"]
Result = {count: 0 for count in CountList}
```

Comment: So if each value ``+5``,such as ``{'zero': 0, 'one': 5, 'two': 10 '......}``.What should I do?

Comment: Do like this: {CountList[i]: i*5 for i in range(len(CountList))}

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
Result=dict(zip(CountList, [0]*len(CountList)))
```

Outputs:

```py
{'zero': 0, 'one': 0, 'two': 0, 'three': 0, 'four': 0, 'five': 0, 'six': 0, 'seven': 0, 'eight': 0, 'nine': 0}
```

Comment: So if each value ``+5``,such as ``{'zero': 0, 'one': 5, 'two': 10 '......}``.What should I do?

Comment: Pretty straight forward: ```Result=dict(zip(CountList, range(0,5*len(CountList),5)))```

Answer (score 1):

That is quite simple:

```
dic={k:0 for k in CountList }
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a function for that...

```
>>> dict.fromkeys(CountList, 0)
{'zero': 0, 'one': 0, 'two': 0, 'three': 0, 'four': 0, 'five': 0, 'six': 0, 'seven': 0, 'eight': 0, 'nine': 0}
```